# Question regarding KKT conditions in optimization

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Following is Proposition 3.3.7 in Bersekas' Nonlinear Programming.

> Let $x^*$ be the local minimum of the problem:
>   $$\text{Minimize }\; f(x)  $$ $$
>      \text{subject to: }\ 
>          h_j(x) = 0, j=1,\dots, m, g_i(x) \le 0, i=1, \dots, r, $$
>   where $f,h_j,g_i$ are continuously differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. $h_j$ are linear, $g_i$ are concave. Then there exists $\lambda_1^*,\dots,\lambda_m^*$ and $\mu_1^*,\dots, \mu_r^*$ such that 
>   (i)$$   \nabla f(x^*) + \sum_{i=1}^r \mu_i \nabla g_i(x^*)
>  + \sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j \nabla h_j(x^*) = 0, $$
>   (ii) $\mu_j^*\ge 0$
>   (iii) In every neighborhood $N$ of $x^*$, there is an $x$ such that $\lambda_i^*h_i(x) > 0$ for all $i$ with $\lambda_i^* \neq 0$ and $\mu_j^*g_j(x) > 0$ for all $j$ with $\mu_j^* \neq 0$.

My question is, is this theorem applicable even in the infinite dimensional case? Specifically, say, is this applicable in the following setting?

> Let  $\alpha >1$. Minimize $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x)^{\alpha}\, dx,$$ subject to
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x)\, dx = 1,$$
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\, p(x)\, dx = a_1,$$
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2\, p(x)\, dx = a_2,$$ and
>   $$p(x)\ge 0.\, \forall x$$

Note that the optimizing variable is $p(x)$, not $x$. Unlike the first one, this has a continuum of inequality constraints, namely, $p(x)\ge 0, \, \forall x$ and it is no more an optimization problem in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is there any theorem which allows us to apply that the same Prop. 3.3.7 even to this setting?

Comment: There are certain similarities, however you don't have gradients you should use functional variations  instead. You have optimal control problem instead of mathematical programming problem.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderVigodner Can you point me a reference?

Comment: The theorem you cited misses an important assumption: existence of a Slater point.

Comment: For infinite-dimensinional problems, see Luenberger - Optimizatio by vector space methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to prove theorems like that one needs the so-called constraint qualifications. Existence of a Slater point if the constraints are convex, for example.

In infinite-dimensional problems similar conditions has to be assumed. On top of the conditions one can expect from finite-dimensional world, there is another type of constraint qualifications involved: certain ranges of of operators have to be closed. (This is not problematic for finite-dimensional problems, where every linear subspace is closed)

Some references could be:

- Luenberger - Optimization by vector space methods
- Barbu, Precupanu - Optimization in Banach spaces